# How can I change the style of the form to display"none" without sending the form?

Tags: html, css

When I click the **Close** button it will send the form to Lcar.php.

I hope it can change the CSS to display "none" and stay on the same webpage.

I don't know why it will send the form to Lcar.php, because the function of the **Close** button only includes document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none"; .

How can I click the **Close** button without sending the form?

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <style>

    body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;} 
    body {background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url(https://illustratedmaps.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/hong-kong-skyline-pen2.jpg)}

    * {box-sizing: border-box;}
    .open-button {
     background-color: #555; 
     color: white;
     padding: 16px 20px;
     border: none; 
     cursor: pointer; 
     opacity: 0.8;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 23px; 
     left: 28px;
     width: 280px; 
    }

    .form-popup { 
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
     bottom: 0; 
     left: 15px;
    boder: 3px solid  #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 9; } 

     .form-container { 
     max-width: 300px;
     padding: 10px; 
     background-color: white; 
     }

     .form-container-input { 
     width: 100%; 
     padding: 15px; 
     margin: 5px 0 22px 0; 
     border: none;
     background: #f1f1f1; }

     .form-container-input-focus{
         background-color: #ddd;
         outline: none; 
    }

    .form-container-btn {
        background-color: #4CAF50; 
        color: white; 
        padding: 16px 20px;
        border: none; 
        cursor: pointer; 
        width: 100%; 
        margin-bottom:10px;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .form-container-cancel {
        background-color: #FF0000; 
        color: white; 
        padding: 16px 20px;
        border: none; 
        cursor: pointer; 
        width: 100%; 
        margin-bottom:10px;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
        opacity: 1; 
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div id="myForm" class="form-popup">
    <form action="Lcar.php" method="post" class="form-container">
    Your Name: <BR>
    <input type="text" value="Enter Your Name" name="aname" class="form-container-input" >
    <br>
    Your Contact Number
    <input type="text" value="Enter Your Contact Number" name="anum" class="form-container-input">
    <br>
    What is your preferred time for us to call you?
    <br>
    Anytime
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="atime" VALUE="at" CHECKED>
    <br>
    Mon-Fri 9am-9pm
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="atime" VALUE="wd">
    <br>
    Sat 9am-1pm
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="atime" VALUE="we">
    <br>
    (except public holidays)
    <br><br>
    Shuttle Services:
    <br>
    <SELECT NAME="services" SIZE=4>
    <OPTION VALUE="1">Limousine</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="2" SELECTED>Luxury Minivans</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="3">Sedans</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="4">SUV</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
    <br><br>

    <INPUT TYPE="submit" class="form-container-btn" value="Send">
    <button class="form-container-cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>

    </form>
    </div>
    <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Contact Us</button> 

    <script> 
    function openForm() {document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";}
    function closeForm(){document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none"; }


    </script> 
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add return false to the the onclick of the close button like so

```
    <button class="form-container-cancel" onclick="closeForm();return false;">Close</button>
```

This will stop the default behavior of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default behaviour of the `submit` event, which is, as the name suggests, submitting the form.

You could add an event listener like this to your javascript:

```js
// [Code to load the submit button]

button.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable submit input using pure Javascript:

```
return false;
```

or JQuery:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Example with pure Javascript:

```
<input type='submit' onsubmit='return false;'>
```

You can also add return false or e.preventDefault() at the end of the wanted function.